# post data not set using jQuery post method on button selected by class

Tags: php, jquery, forms

This site has been really helpful while writing this program. Unfortunately, I hit a snag at some point, and have boiled the problem down quite a bit since. At this point, I am looking at three files, a .html that contains a form, a .js that contains my event handlers, and a .php that receives my post variables and contains new content for the form.

I am getting the post data from the initial text input just fine. The new form content is set as I would expect. However, after this form content is set to a new input of type button with a class of button, the post method in my button class handler is not setting post data on login.php as I expect it to.

Here is my code:

Contents of interface.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="interface" action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" value="enter username here" name="user"/>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<script src='events.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of events.js file:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
  $.post(
    $("#interface").attr("action"),
    $(":input").serialize(),
    function(info){$("#interface").html(info);}
  );
}); 
$(".button").click(function(){
  var $this=$(this);
  $.post(
    $("#interface").attr("action"),
    {data:$this.val()},
    function(info){$("#interface").html(info);}
  );
}); 
$("#interface").submit(function(){
  return false;
});
```

Contents of login.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user'])){
  echo '<input type="button" class="button" value="set data"/>';
}else if(isset($_POST['data'])){
  echo 'data is set';
}
?>
```

Comment: two problems here. first, you can combine the click event and the submit event into 1 (and you should, just use the submit event.) Secondly, you need to bind to the click event of `.button` after you add it, not before.

Comment: Yes, I copied the script tags for src="events.js" to the bottom of login.php and that solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would definitely mark this as the correct answer, though I don't see how to do it in a comment. I'll toss you some rep or something.

Comment: well, that's likely the wrong way to solve the problem. usually best to not include js in ajax loaded content.

Comment: I thought that's what you meant by binding the event after the button is added.

Comment: I meant for it to be inside of the $.post callback, but then when i was setting up my sample i realized that it would be infinitely redundant, so it either needs to use event delegation to bind to the button, or stop binding to the button completely. It's much easier to just stop binding to the button.

Comment: I liked the idea of setting a hidden input to the value of the button clicked instead of having an event handler keeping an eye out for every button. I'm assuming that would free up some memory.

Comment: well, you'd still need a click event listening for button clicks so that you can set the value of the input to the value of the button clicked, right?

Comment: Yeah. I'm setting an onClick attribute for every button type input that passes the button's value into a function that gets everything ready to be posted to login.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until the button exists to bind an event to it. Additionally, i'd switch from click to submit and drop the click event binding on .button completely.

```
//$("#submit").click(function () {
$("#interface").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this), data = $form.serialize();
    if ($form.find(".button").length && $form.find(".button").val() ) {
        data = {data: $form.find(".button").val()};
    }
    $.post($form.attr("action"), data, function (info) {
        $form.html(info);
    });
});

//$("#interface").submit(function () {
//    return false;
//});
```

Since the form is not being replaced, and the event is on the form, you no longer need to re-bind anything.

Comment: I need some kind of click event handler, because I will have multiple buttons in the form at times. If I submit the value of all the buttons, I won't know which one was clicked. That being said, I am marking this answer correct, because I did not know that I needed to bind the event after the input is created and that solved my problem.

Comment: All you need is the value from the button right? just get that and send it. (updating)

Comment: How is that possible after the form is submitted? Don't I need a click event handler to know if a button is clicked? I mean, I could be wrong.

Comment: in this case we don't care at all if the button is clicked. When the button is clicked or a user presses enter on an input/button, the form is submitted. we're catching that form submitted event.

Comment: Agreed. If only someone would buy this program as is. *sigh*

Comment: Hypothetically though, what would you do to optimize the program if there were two buttons in the form?

Comment: iirc, If the clicked button has a value, it will be sent to the server if you use `$form.serialize()`. Though, now that i think about it, i'm unsure if that's actually the case.

Comment: Looks like that isn't the case. In that case i'd delegate a click event to the buttons that either set the value of a hidden input, or replaces the submit event entirely.